# Using ifelse and mutate to categorise a new column by previous column name

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I am having issues where I need to categorise US states assigning two groups of five states as either rich or poor and every other state as middle. I am able to simply categorise as either rich or not using this code:

```r
twoe.data.frame <-
  mutate(us_contagious_diseases,
         wealth = ifelse(
           state == "Maryland" | state == "New Jersey" | state == "hawaii" |
             state == "Massachusetts" | state == "Connecticut",
           "rich", "middle"))
```

Whilst I am struggling to figure out how to assign the other five states (not included in above code) to be considered poor.

I am very New to R and am unsure how to do this across the three conditions being rich, middle and poor. I can only seem to do two at a time.

What needs to be added to my code to classify the states of Louisiana, New Mexico, Arkansas, Mississippi, West Virginia as poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case_when` to assign `wealth` based on state name.

```
library(dplyr)

us_contagious_diseases %>%
    mutate(wealth = case_when(state %in% c('Maryland', 'New Jersey', 'hawaii', 'Massachusetts', 'Connecticut') ~ 'rich', 
                              state %in% c('Louisiana', 'New Mexico', 'Arkansas', 'Mississippi', 'West Virginia') ~ 'poor',
                              TRUE ~ 'middle'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much this has worked! I think I can see where I was going wrong running along a different route thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`, we can use `fcase`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(us_contagious_diseases)[, wealth := fcase(state %chin% 
   c('Maryland', 'New Jersey', 'hawaii', 'Massachusetts', 'Connecticut'), 'rich',
  state %in% c('Louisiana', 'New Mexico', 'Arkansas', 'Mississippi', 'West Virginia'),  'poor' , 
       default = 'middle')][]
```